# jQuery binding multiple events, and pass data

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I know we can have this in 1.4:

```
$("a").bind({
  click : clickFn,
  mouseover: mouseFn
});
```

and that is nice and I would like to use it, but it seems like there is no way to pass extra data to events bound this way, it needs to be done the 'old way':

```
$("a").bind("click", {"some":"data"}, clickFn);
```

**Question:**
How can I pass the extra data to my event call backs and bind multiple events in a single bind at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
$("a").bind({
  click : function() { clickFn.apply(this, [param1,param2,..]); },
  mouseover: function() { mouseFn.apply(this, [param1,param2,..]); }
});
```

although you would need to make your functions accept parameters in this way ..

***[made an update to maintain context]***

Comment: good idea. though you are missing the event param now, but i can add that in.